# Javascript change attribute wont take effect after attribute set on load

Tags: javascript, html

I rendered a page with a css class fade-in effect on images.
So that when I load the page I have 4 images that load and they have a fade in effect. Now I have a button that when clicked it changes an image and I want to have the same effect on the new image that appears.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="card d-flex justify-content-center ml-3 mr-3 mt-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img id="card-num-1" src="/static/TarotCards/tarot-back/tarot-back.jpg" class="card- 
                 img-top fade-in-onload" alt="..." style="width: 180px;height: 300px; margin-left: 
                 18%;">
    <div class="card-body justify-content-center">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p id="wow" class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title 
                 and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <button id="reveal-1" onclick="card_reveal_1()" class="btn btn-outline-dark 
                ">reveal</button>
        <button id="replace_1" onclick="replaceCard_1()" disabled="true" class="btn btn- 
                outline-dark rep">replace</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code is:

```
function card_reveal_1() {

        document.getElementById("card-num-1").setAttribute("src", `/{{ cards[0]["CARD_PATH"] 
        }}`);
        let toDisable = document.createAttribute("disabled");
        toDisable.value = "true";
        document.getElementById("reveal-1").setAttribute("disabled", "true");

        //  -------- that is the place that the set attribute happen ------ 
        
        let fade = document.getElementsByClassName("card-img-top")
        fade[0].setAttribute("class", "card-img-top wow wow fade-in-image")

        // --------------------------------------
        indicator += 1;
        if (indicator == 4) {
            let toEnable = document.getElementsByClassName("rep");
            for (let i = 0; i < toEnable.length; i++) {
                toEnable[i].removeAttribute("disabled")
            }
        }

    }
```

My problem is that when I look at the dev-tools in the browser it gets updated but there is no fade in effect.

I tried to do it by creating an attribute and changing it with the `setAttribute` function. I also tried to remove the class and add it again.

Comment: Without seeing the CSS classes you've created for this, we're just guessing what could be wrong. Also, you are setting class "wow" twice, which isn't necessary.

Comment: the wow wow is just a test for me to see the change i will add the css too

Comment: for some reason i cant edit the original question and cant add the css code :(

Comment: It looks like someone else edited your question and is waiting for approval for the edit. You should be able to either approve or disapprove the edit, then add the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

add the class after image is loaded:

```js
var indicator = 0

var img = document.getElementById("card-num-1");

img.onload = () => {
  img.classList.add('fade-in-image');
}

function card_reveal_1() {;

  img.classList.remove('fade-in-image');

  img.setAttribute("src", indicator % 2 ? 'https://via.placeholder.com/250' : 'https://via.placeholder.com/150');

  indicator += 1;


}
```

```css
.fade-in-image {
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 3s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 3s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 3s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card d-flex justify-content-center ml-3 mr-3 mt-3" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img id="card-num-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="card-img-top fade-in-onload" alt="..." style="width: 180px;height: 300px; margin-left: 18%;">
  <div class="card-body justify-content-center">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p id="wow" class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <button id="reveal-1" onclick="card_reveal_1()" class="btn btn-outline-dark
            ">load new</button>
  </div>
</div>
```